# numpy function which converts an array of '+'/'-' chars to an array of +/-1 int values

Tags: python, numpy, coordinates, astropy

I have an array like this:

```py
sign_char_array = np.array(['+', '-', '+', '+'])
# dtype='<U1'
```

I'd like to convert this into an array of +1 and -1 values (so that it is easy to multiply this array of signs with an array of corresponding integer or float values). I'd like the final output to be:

```py
converted_sign_array = np.array([1, -1, 1, 1])
```

I know that I can write the following line of code to do this manually:

```py
2 * (sign_char_array == '+').astype('int') - 1
# array([ 1, -1,  1,  1])
```

However, I am curious: is there a built-in `numpy` or `astropy` function which does this conversion?

For context: I'm an astronomer and I work often with published scientific tables that provide [sexagesimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexagesimal) coordinates. Sometimes the sign of the latitude/[declination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declination) coordinate is provided as its own data column of strings, rather than being included as a sign in front of the next column.

Comment: I can't think of a better.  Personally, that's exactly how I would have done it.

Comment: @0x5453 I think that's it! Wow. Would you post that as an "Answer" so that I can mark it correct? I had no idea np.where took additional arguments in this way.

Comment: I'd do `2 * (sign_char_array == '+').view(np.int8) - 1`. Saving that one tiny temp array feels nice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) is the first thing that comes to mind, though I'm sure there are many ways of accomplishing the same thing.

```
converted_sign_array = np.where(sign_char_array == '+', 1, -1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a number of options:

- The best is likely [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), covered in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68041529/2988730).
- For two options, you can use direct indexing:

  ```
   np.array([+1, -1])[(sign_char_array == '+').view(np.int8)]
  ```
- [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) is a generalization that allows you to potentially add more options to the input:

  ```
   result = np.select([sign_char_array == '+',  sign_char_array == '-'], [1, -1])
  ```

  you can simplify the computation of the first argument using broadcasting. This also allows you to expand the options:

  ```
   result = np.select(sign_char_array == [['+'],  ['-'], ['t']], [1, -1, 2])
  ```
- [`np.choose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html) is an index-based function similar to `np.select`:

  ```
   _, i = np.unique(sign_char_array, return_inverse=True)
   result = np.choose(i, [1, -1])
  ```

  You can generalize this to many options using a mapping and the fact that the output of [`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) is sorted:

  ```
   map_in = np.array(['+', '-', 't'])
   map_out = np.array([1, -1, 2])

   _, i = np.unique(sign_char_array, return_inverse=True)
   result = np.choose(i, map_out[map_in.argsort()])
  ```

  You can turn this into a one-liner by replacing `i` with `np.unique(sign_char_array, return_inverse=True)[1]`. This method looks more complex than using `np.select`, but it is actually more efficient.